# confusion understanding/interpreting power spectrum of audio in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio, power-spectral-density, audio-processing, music

Please find attached snapshot. I am confused regarding power spectrum in MATLAB as according to google definition in attached snapshot"the distribution of the energy of a waveform among its different frequency components."

But how can we interpret the spectrum displayed in MATLAB where we have values in negative db and lower frequency components (almost before 0.5pi radians) has less negative value of power spectrum

**Does it means ,the lesser the negative db value is, more impact it has in audio signal??**or my understanding is wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: that's not a "google definition"; it's literally just taken out of context from Oxford dictionary. Please don't post screenshot of text, either – copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 2):

**1.- Power Spectral Density units** `[W/Hz]`

Let be `x(t)` the `670000` samples of the input signal displayed in this question

**2.- PSD varies with time window**

Then if you put all `670000` audio samples `x(t)` at once into the `PSD` function, whatever it is the code used, then one obtains the particular `PSD` shown below the time samples, the curve you are asking clarification about.

However, if you time gate the time signal `x(t)` to let's say `10000` samples at a time, upon calculating `67` different `PSD` you will obtain a more accurate `PSD` of `x(t)`, as long as the time window is short enough to include at least one pitch cycle of what seems to be human speech, but long enough for the processing unit to generate `67` different `PSD` frames without falling behind, this meaning, in real time.

**3.- Where did you find the definition of** `PSD`

Please note that saying you found the 'definition of PSD in Google' is not the same as having found the definition of PSD using Google in for instance [Wolfram Mathworld definition of PSD](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralPowerDensity.html)

or in [AP website PSD definition](https://www.ap.com/blog/fft-spectrum-and-spectral-densities-same-data-different-scaling/#:%7E:text=The%20Power%20Spectral%20Density%20is%20also%20derived%20from,and%20FS%202%20%2FHz%20in%20the%20digital%20domain)

or in Wikipedia, that virtually any one can edit

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density

**4.- `ESD` vs `PSD`**

**Energy Spectral Density ESD** : units `[V^2/(s*Hz)]`

is not the same as

**Power Spectral Density PSD** units `[V^2/Hz]`

**5.- Power Spectrum amplitude values are always positive**

Signals in dB scaling basics available for instance in the following links :

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/rf-principles-components/the-rf-engineers-guide-to-the-decibel/

https://handsonrf.com/db-dbm-dbw-dbc-basics/

**6.- dB vs dBA**

**6.1.- signal level or power level**

`dB` can be used as a unitless ratio, for signal levels `Volt` `Amp` .., and as used here for signal power, it's actually `dBW`. People using `dBW` all day just skip the 'W' and may simply use `dB`.

When handling smaller power levels one may also use `dBmW` that if being used all day, one may simplify to just `dBm`.

Be aware that some careless people mix `dB(V)` and `dB(W)`, as well as `dBm(V)` with `dBm(W)`.

You really have to stop them right on the first ambiguity and find ways to avoid misunderstandings by omission of otherwise key units.

**6.2.- dBA**

`A` in `dBA` stands for `Audio`

these

[image]

from https://www.amateur-radio-wiki.net/decibels/

are `dBA`

`dBA` are audio signal power pondered, weighted, with a particular standard curve agreed among experts that resembles human ear response.

**6.3.- dB(W) to dB(W)**

to translate between dB(W) and dBA(W) a standard weight curve is used
[https://acousticalengineer.com/a-weighting-table/#:~:text=To%20determine%20A-weighted%20decibel%20values%20%28dBA%29%2C%20add%20the,frequency%20band%20to%20the%20unweighted%20decibel%20level%20%28dB%29](https://acousticalengineer.com/a-weighting-table/#:%7E:text=To%20determine%20A-weighted%20decibel%20values%20%28dBA%29%2C%20add%20the,frequency%20band%20to%20the%20unweighted%20decibel%20level%20%28dB%29).

**7.- It's important to know the reference impedance of Audio signals**

This is, when working with audio signal powers.

While RF signals are commonly on `50 Ohm` (VHF and some UHF on `75 Ohm` though) audio signals on microphones, speakers, analog phone lines, recording systems or else, can be found on a wide range of impedance values.

A good read to understand this point is available here
https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/understanding-impedance

**8.- To really call it power an impedance reference is required**

All the above literature references tacitcly assume `1 Ohm` as the reference impedance used to obtain signal power out of the signal amplitude values, let's assume with units `[V]` Volts.

**SUMMARY**

So as you have taken the `PSD`, all samples at once, it may be the case that wide silence gaps between busy bursts 'water down' the actual impact of the `PSD` on human ears.

Also taking small time windows or gates is the standard way to begin with speech recognition as too long feeds into `PSD` cannot possibly generate specific pitch markers that help tell whether the signal is on a 'f' or an 'e', for instance, in a way to speak.

Therefore, I suggest you repeat the experiment with shorter frames

```
n1=1e4;  % basic input time window
for k=1:1:67
X1=PSD(x([1:n1]+(k-1)*n1));
..  % stack them up
end

% display each X1
```

The `PSD` obtained this way to use `PSD` to analyse signals rather than  feeding the whole sequence at once.

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed response. What i am able to understand from your answer is that whatever music/audio file we may be considering,we will get the exactly same plot of PSD as shown in my attached snap(unless we change frame rate as you mentioned at end of your answer)??

Comment: the audio of an audio signal, human speech, music, looks for instance like this https://www.videezy.com/abstract/38030-digital-audio-spectrum-sound-equalizer-effect as you can see it changes with time, I should check but I guess it's about 20ms window. Because of the nature of the audio time signal, the spectrum of this signal changes spectral density with time. As done in your question, you send to spectrum the entire audio signal in 1 chunk, not in 20ms, stepped or sliding, so you only get a single spectrum frame.

Comment: If you do not break down the time signal into small enough frames, short enough, but not too short, then there's loss of spectral contents. The input time signal is not just 1 spectral frame. It's a sequence of spectrum 'photos' 20ms apart in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret the MATLAB representation as a Power Spectral Density (PSD) in logarithmic scale (dB that is) normalised to some specific value. I am not sure exactly how the power is normalised in the implementation you have used though.

Nevertheless, unless you are aiming for absolute values, in which case you would also have to calibrate your equipment (it is not stated whether this is the case or not in the question), you could renormalise that to $0$ dB by adding the maximum value of your PSD to all the values in the vector. Then the negative values would declare how lower each frequency component's amplitude is compared to the highest amplitude in dB.

Now, regarding the interpretation of the results you would have to provide some more information on where and how you got these results. If this is the result of a system then it could most probably be the power response of the system. If they are taken from a transfer function, then they would correspond to the effect the transfer function has on a signal/system.

Judging from the image you posted, this is the PSD of some signal, which, roughly speaking, denotes the Power Spectral Density of the signal or else, the distribution of the energy of the signal per frequency.